# MySQL join on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need to do a search on 2 simultaneous tables, and I thought that this join would work but its giving me an incorrect syntax error.

```
$return_arr = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lastname LIKE '$q%' AND agencyid = '$agencyid'
                          UNION
                          SELECT * FROM busclients WHERE busname LIKE '$q%' AND agencyid = '$agencyid'")or die(mysql_error());
            if($query) {
                while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    if(isset($result['busname'])){
                        $description['id'] = $result['ID'];
                    $description['value'] = $result['busname'] ;
                    array_push($return_arr,$description);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $description['id'] = $result['ID'];
                    $description['value'] = $result['lastname'] . ", " . $result['firstname'] ;
                    array_push($return_arr,$description);    
                    }

                    }
                }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

*Edited with fix suggested below and entire syntax*

This is a query from an autocomplete search box. So when someone types in a client or business client name, it uses this query to search the database and then displays the results using jquery.

The fix below works but when I do a search on a business client it is returning []. A client search works fine.

Comment: This is wrong: WHERE lastname, busname

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Your non-working query does not convey what you really want to do.

Comment: Describe in the question, what your `WHERE` clause is supposed to do. (As @RobertRozas stated, your WHERE clause is the problem)

Comment: Redefine your question...also explain from which table belogs lastname, busname and agencyid

Answer (score 0):

You could use two seperate query's and join them together like so:

```
SELECT * FROM clients
WHERE lastname LIKE "%agencyid%"

UNION 

SELECT * FROM busclients
WHERE busname LIKE "%$agencyid%";
```

Comment: Only if the two table structures contain the same columns and data types.

Comment: This works but when I do a search on a busclients it is returning []. When I do a search on the clients it returns correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You sql syntax shoul look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM clients c
inner join 
busclients b 
on c.agencyid=b.idbus 
WHERE (c.lastname and  b.busname LIKE '$q%') AND c.agencyid = '$agencyid'
```

Just to complete the circle make sure you read [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) on how to join tables in mysql

Comment: I highly doubt this. `c.lastname` as the boolean expression is not very likely

Comment: when i do this it gives me an error saying agencyid is ambiguous?

Comment: This query i have done it blind !! you need to put you metadata in the body of you question , so we can analyze it better !