# MySQL Union Losing Table Names

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have a MySQL query where I am trying to search 2 tables simultaneously. This is for an autocomplete search box that searches for regular clients and business clients. Here is the code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lastname LIKE '$q%' AND agentid = '$agentid'
                          UNION
                          SELECT * FROM busclients WHERE busname LIKE '$q%' AND agentid = '$agentid'")or die(mysql_error());
            if($query) {
                while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $busname = $result['busname'];
                    print_r($result);

                    if(isset($busname)){

                        $description['id'] = 'viewbusiness.php?id=' . $result['ID'];
                    $description['value'] = $busname ;
                    array_push($return_arr,$description);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    $description['id'] = 'viewclient.php?id=' .$result['ID'];
                    $description['value'] = $result['lastname'] . ", " . $result['firstname'] ;
                    array_push($return_arr,$description); 
                    }

                    }
                }
```

The problem is that the business clients get assigned the table names from the regular clients, so the code never uses the if(isset($busname)) because busname becomes lastname instead, and directs you to the veiwclient page.

Comment: You might need to change your query to use a JOIN so that busname and lastname would be separate fields in the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL join on 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096814/mysql-join-on-2-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  a.lastname , 
  b.busname 
FROM clients as a 
INNER JOIN  
  busclients as b 
  on b.agent_id = a.agent_id 
WHERE a.agent_id = $agent_id 
      AND (a.lastname LIKE '$q%' OR b.busname LIKE '$q%')
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (a.lastname LIKE 'crea%' OR b.busname LIKE 'crea%')' at line 3

Comment: aah.. i had missed bits in the query... updated query .. please try now.

Comment: did Select a.lastname , b.busname 
                                from clients as a inner join busclients as b on busclients.agentid = clients.agentid 
                                where a.agentid = '$agentid' AND (a.lastname LIKE '$q%' OR b.busname LIKE '$q%') and got Unknown column 'busclients.agentid' in 'on clause', but agentid exists within both tables.

Answer (score 0):

By specifically selecting the column names you want from that table, and selecting a blank string for the others, I believe you can get the results you're looking for using something like this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, '' AS busname FROM clients WHERE ... UNION SELECT '' AS firstname, '' AS lastname, busname FROM busclients WHERE ...
```